# Android Studio launches app on wrong emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, deployment, android-emulator

I'm debugging on two different emulators: a tablet, and a smartphone.

So when I debug, I'm prompted to choose on which device the app should be launched.

It doesn't matter which emulator I choose, it always launches the app on the first one in the list.

[image]

Comment: check whether one which is not loading is having min api less than required ?

Comment: @Harry API is 21 for both devices

Comment: Did you try resetting ADB? Open a terminal and type `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`. Often this sets things straight, worth trying.